# Amazon Advertising API - Creating a new sponsored product campaign

Tags: ads, amazon-advertising-api

I'm trying to create new sponsored products campaigns from the amazon advertising API but I'm having some problems with the API documentation. I can't find any information on how to create an advertising campaign for a specific product.

Do you have any idea on how to get my products ASINs once I have my profile ID?

How do you declare for witch product you want to create a new campaign?

I'm still waiting a response from the Advertising API support

Answer (score 1):

Creating a campaign is just a shell. You need to create a product ad which takes in the parameters adGroupId, campaignId, and asin.

Mess around with the actual advertising portal to get a sense of what the API is trying to re-create.